# HttpContext session within a custom class is always null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, httpcontext

I'm trying to access a session variable inside a custom class like so:

Controller:

```
    public void RemoveMachinesListChanged(object sender, RemovePackageEvent e)
    {
        PackageActionStatus.Current.Machines = e.Machines;
        // Dictionary<int, int> machines =  e.Machines;
    }
```

---

```
public class PackageActionStatus
{
    public static PackageActionStatus Current
    {
        get
        {
            HttpContextWrapper context = new HttpContextWrapper(System.Web.HttpContext.Current);
            var session = (PackageActionStatus)context.Session["PackageActionStatus"];
            if (session == null)
            {
                session = new PackageActionStatus();
                context.Session["PackageActionStatus"] = session;
            }

            return session;
        }
    }

    private Dictionary<int, int> machines;

    public Dictionary<int, int> Machines
    {
        get
        {
            return this.machines;
        }
        set
        {
            if (this.machines == null)
            {
                this.machines = new Dictionary<int, int>();
            }

            this.machines = value;
        }
    }
}
```

What i'm trying to achieve here is store and retrieve values from/to session variable via AJAX call. It seems that whenever I use ajax HttpContext is null. How would I do it?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HttpContext is available in certain points of request life-cycle. In addition, it's only available in the request's thread.

Implement an `IHttpHandler`, which has `ProcessRequest` method having the instance of request's `HttpContext` as input parameter (learn more on MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttphandler.aspx).

Check a `ProcessRequest` sample implementation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttphandler.processrequest.aspx

Comment: how?. I don't quite understand :(

Comment: You need to implement that interface `IHttpHandler`. An HTTP Handler could be a page, but yours is just a black box that gets an AJAX requests and store something in session or wherever you want. Once you've created your own HTTP Handler (call it `SessionStorageHandler`), you need to register it in your Web.config. Finally, calling an url like `http://localhost/yourhandler` with HTTP POST (or other like PUT), will invoke your whole `ProcessRequest`method that you implemented before!

Comment: see, that's the problem, "RemoveMachinesListChanged" is not getting called by ajax. It's an event listener that gets raised when "e.Machines" changes. I need to store e.Machines Dictionary<int, int> in a session at this point.

Comment: @ShaneKm Then you need to re-think your solution. I'm pretty sure that IHttpHandler is your way to go. Just try to think how.